# Dynamically switch the databaseId in MyBatis

Tags: mybatis, spring-mybatis

I am using MyBatis Multi DB Support for connecting to Oracle and PostgreS.
http://www.mybatis.org/mybatis-3/configuration.html#databaseIdProvider

I have a single software stack which initially runs queries on Oracle. On a flip of switch, I want the same software stack to run queries on PostgreSQL. So I have used the MyBatis Multi DB Support feature in order to run different SQL fragments based on the vendor. e.g. 'dual' is not available in PostgreS but in Oracle.

When I flip the switch, the *_databaseId* attribute remains assigned to Oracle and hence PostgreS SQL fragment doesn't runs. When I restart my software stack, *_databaseId* attribute gets assigned to PostgreSQL and the corresponding SQL fragment runs.

My use-case is that I don't want to restart my service in order to make it to run the right PostgreSQL query. What can I do to solve this issue?

Comment: Apparently it looks like I am asking the same thing which has been asked 6 months ago.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45503291/applying-databaseid-of-mybatis-to-dynamic-datasource?rq=1